# bash script to get current line and row not working

Tags: bash, tput

ive written the following script to print out the current line and row every time it changes aka every time i press up,down,left or right but the output is always the same:

```
row:43:col:141
```

i believe this means top left of the screen where 0 0 would be bottom right, but im not too sure.

heres my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "press a key"
tput clear
row=$(tput lines)
col=$(tput cols)
while true; do
        echo "row:$row:col:$col"
        K1=,K2=,K3=
        read -s -N1
        K1="$REPLY"
        read -s -N1 -t 0.001
        K2="$REPLY"
        read -s -N1 -t 0.001
        K3="$REPLY"
        key="$K1$K2$K3"
        case "$key" in
                $'\033[A') tput cuu 1;;
                $'\033[B') tput cud 1;;
                $'\033[C') tput cuf 1;;
                $'\033[D') tput cup $row $(($col-1));;
                *) echo "pressed a key!";;
        esac
                row=$(tput lines)
                col=$(tput cols)
done

exit 0
```

apparently theres no way to move the cursor left using tput, so I used:

```
tput cup $row $(($col-1))
```

but this doesn't work either, any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Your `tput clear` resets the row snd column values.

Comment: its only run once tho and row and col are being updated with every key press

Comment: Install (or see if already installed) `ncurses` and `ncurses-doc`. Read their `man` pages. Trying to read "cursor control sequences" through timing, and trying to do microsecond timing in `bash` are both impractical ideas. Is this an XY problem? What are you really trying to do? Please [edit] your Question, or ask a new one. Do not reply via Add Comment.

Comment: `row` and `col` are not being updated **at all**. They are being set to the window size every time, *not* the cursor position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tput lines` and `tput cols` return the current size of the window in character units. If you drag the window to change its size, you will (usually) see the new values change interactively. They have nothing to do with the cursor position.

Also, the top left of the window is (0,0). Your bottom right is currently (42,140), because the positions are zero-based.

`tput cub1` should move left. All of `cub1`, `cuf1`, `cuu1`, `cud1` are single words -- no spaces. There is no cub2 etc. Also, `tput cud1` moves the cursor to the *first* column of the line below: `tput cuu1` stays in the *same* column of the line above. (This may be a bug in my configuration, though.)

I don't think there is a tput option to read the cursor position. It is considered to be the programmer's responsibility to keep track of where it ended up, or to move the cursor to where the next text output should be placed. You can save one location with `tput sc`, and restore that location (maybe multiple times) with `tput rc`.

cursor_address (cup), column_address (hpa) and row_address (vpa) take absolute row and column numbers (zero based) and are more useful than the one-char moves.

The full set of terminal commands should be documented in `man -s 5 terminfo`, but `tput` is a fairly clunky tool (a new process for every command), so `ncurses` (or at least `C`) is needed for any serious work.

This is my brief check on how these work on my `TERM=xterm-256color`.

```
#! /bin/bash

clear
r=$( tput lines ); c=$( tput cols )
for (( k = 1; k <= $(( r * c )); ++k )); do printf '.'; done
tput cup 0 0
printf 'At 0,0'
sleep 2

for ((k = 1; k <= 20; ++k)); do tput cud1; done
for ((k = 1; k <= 20; ++k)); do tput cuf1; done
printf 'At 20,20'
sleep 2

tput cuu1; for ((k = 1; k <= 8; ++k)); do tput cub1; done
printf 'Up one: Hello, World'
sleep 2

tput cup 10 10
printf 'At 10,10'
sleep 2

tput cud1; tput cud1; printf 'Down two: Hello, World'
sleep 5

tput cup $(( r - 1 )) 0
printf '\n\n\n\n\n'
```

EDIT:

You can optimise the code by asking `tput` once for each sequence you expect to use, and having a function that does repeats. This will avoid calling so many external processes, and make the code simpler and more readable.

The code below illustrates these optimisations. There is a fair amount of one-time code to fetch the tput sequences and define utility functions. After that, the actual display work is brief, efficient, and fairly readable.

Process substitution does not work well on these sequences: for example, it removes newlines. The method below (read, refusing all delimiters) is robust.

```
#! /bin/bash

Tget () {   #:: Args (var, seq) -- Get a tput outcome.
    declare -n var="$1"; shift
    IFS='' read -d '' -r var < <( tput "${@}" )
}

Tget lines lines; Tget cols cols;
lines=$(( lines )); cols=$(( cols ));   #.. Bug with newlines.
Tget tUp cuu1; Tget tDown cud1; Tget tBack cub1; Tget tFrwd cuf1;
Tget tGoTo cup 35 37;
tGoTo="${tGoTo//3?/%d}"     #.. Parameterise the row and col numbers.

GoTo () {   #:: Args (line, col) -- one-based.
    printf "${tGoTo}" "$1" "$2"
}
Put () {    #:: Args (n, str) -- Repeat a string n times.
    typeset k
    for (( k = 1; k <= "$1"; ++k )); do printf '%s' "${2}"; done
}
At () {     #:: Args (line, col, text)
    GoTo "$1" "$2"; printf '%s' "$3"
}

#.. Demonstrate the resources.
GoTo 1 1; Put $(( lines * cols )) "."
At 1 11 'At 1,11:       My Title Goes Here      '; sleep 2 
Put 20 "$tDown"; Put 15 "$tFrwd"; printf 'At 21,16'; sleep 2 
Put 1 "$tUp"; Put 8 "$tBack"; printf 'Up one: Hello, World'; sleep 2 
At 10 10 'At 10,10: Updated This Space'; sleep 2 
At 10 10 'At 10,10: Updated Again     '; sleep 2 
Put 2 "$tDown"; printf 'Down two: Goodbye, World'; sleep 5 
GoTo "$lines" 1; Put 5 "$tDown"; sleep 2 
printf "That's All, Folks!" 
Put $(( lines - 30 )) "$tDown"
```

Answer (score 2):

This code illustrates how the cursor keys can be used to move an `X` around the screen.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
rows=$(tput lines) cols=$(tput cols)    # Screen size
row=$((rows/2)) col=$((cols/2))         # Initial cursor position

# Cursor key codes (would have preferred to derive these from terminfo)
cku=$'\033[A' ckd=$'\033[B' ckr=$'\033[C' ckl=$'\033[D'

# Save the terminal state and then disable echo
stty=$(stty -g)
stty -echo

# Here we go
while :
do
    # Erase previous marker
    [[ -n "$orow" ]] && [[ -n "$ocol" ]] && [[ "$orow$ocol" != "$row$col" ]] &&
        { tput civis; tput cup $orow $ocol; printf ' \b'; tput cnorm; }
    
    # Status line
    # { tput sc; tput civis; tput cup 1 1; printf "Cursor (%d,%d) key was '%s'    " $col $row "$(printf '%s' "$key" | od -xc | xargs)"; tput rc; tput cnorm; }
    { tput sc; tput civis; tput cup 1 1; printf 'Cursor (%d,%d)  ' $col $row; tput rc; tput cnorm; }

    # Place the cursor at its new point
    { tput civis; tput cup $row $col; printf 'X\b'; tput cnorm; }

    # Read upto three character codes from the keyboard
    k1= k2= k3=
    read -N1 k1; [[ "$k1" = $'\033' ]] && { read -N1 -t0.1 k2; [[ "$k2" = '[' ]] && { read -N1 -t0.1 k3; }; }
    key="$k1$k2$k3"

    # Save current position and determine new position. Prevent overflow
    orow=$row ocol=$col
    case $key in
        ("$cku")        ((row--)); [[ $row -lt 0 ]] && row=$orow ;;
        ("$ckd")        ((row++)); [[ $row -ge $rows ]] && row=$orow ;;
        ("$ckl")        ((col--)); [[ $col -lt 0 ]] && col=$ocol ;;
        ("$ckr")        ((col++)); [[ $col -ge $cols ]] && col=$ocol ;;
        ($'\033')       break ;;    # ESC = quit
    esac
done

# Reset the terminal characteristics (i.e. re-enable echo)
stty "$stty"
echo
exit 0
```

Screen size is `0 ≤ row < rows` and `0 ≤ col < cols`.

Use cursor keys to move around, <kbd>Esc</kbd> to quit. It wouldn't be difficult to modify the code for the left/right operations to handle wraparound. Nor would it be terribly hard to allow printing characters to write to the screen, word-processor style.